# Order of $37$-Sylow subgroup of ideal class group of $K_{37} = \Bbb Q(\mu_{37^{n}})$ is known to be $37^n$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, number-fields, iwasawa-theory

I want to examine nontrivial examples of what we call Iwasawa class formula,
$c(n)=\mu p^n + \lambda n + \nu$, where $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbf N$ and $\nu \in \mathbf Z$ are parameters depending only on $K$ (number field), and $c(n)$ is order of $p$-Sylow subgroup of ideal class group of $K$.

Order of $37$-Sylow subgroup of ideal class group of $K_{37} = \Bbb Q(\mu_{37^{n}})$ is known to be $37^n$.

I heard this fact follows from Iwasawa theory.
But how? And why $37$ is special (Maybe because it is an irregular prime? Does this become difficult with another (regular) prime?)

Self contained proof or reference (pdf, website...etc) is also welcomed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This link](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~chaoli/tutorial2012/Lecture14.pdf) mentions that the $37$-group of $C(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{37^n}))$ is the cyclic group of order $37^n$ and that the $691$-group of $C(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{691^n}))$ is the product of two cyclic groups of order $691^n$.

Answer (score 4):

Much more than Iwasawa's original theorem is known by now. First of all, the $p$-primary part of the class group stays trivial in the field $K_n=\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^{n+1}})$ unless it is already non-trivial for $K_0=\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$. See Proposition 13.22 in Washington's "Introduction to cyclotomic fields". Therefore the only primes of interest are the irregular primes and the first one is $p=37$. Ribet's results showing the converse to Herbrand's theorem lets you even determine the structure of the class group of $K_0$ with its action by the Galois group of $K_0/\mathbb{Q}$ in terms of Bernoulli numbers. It is known that $\mu=0$. Furthermore, the main conjecture is known, which means that the constant $\lambda$, and in fact most things about the limit class group as a $\Lambda$-module, can be determined from a $p$-adic zeta-function that can be calculated either using Stickelberger elements (so Bernoulli numbers) or modular forms. The constant $\nu$ and the constant $n_0$ such that Iwasawa's theorem is valid for $n\geq n_0$ can often be determined, too.

A lot of these things are in Washington's book. Lang's "Cyclotomic Field" is another standard reference.

I know too little about explicit calculations of these invariants. But I would expect that it becomes harder as the irregularity of the prime increases.

For the special case of $p=37$, I once did the explicit calculation for a lecture series in Heidelberg. The Bernoulli number $B_{32}$ is divisible by $37$. Accordingly, we expect a non-trivial $\omega^5$ part in the $p$-primary part of the class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{37})$ where $\omega$ is the Teichmüller character. Indeed the approximation to the $37$-adic $L$-function for this character is
\begin{multline*}
 14\cdot 37 + 33\cdot 37^2 + 13\cdot 37^3 + \mathbf{O}(37^4) + \bigl(16 + 6\cdot 37 + 32\cdot 37^2 +  \mathbf{O}(37^3)\bigr)\cdot T \\
                     + \bigl(29 + 9\cdot 37 + 13\cdot 37^2 +  \mathbf{O}(37^3)\bigr)\cdot T^2 + \mathbf{O}(T^3).
\end{multline*}
This is not a unit as $-B_{1,\omega^{-5}}$ is divisible by $37$. From the fact that the second coefficient is a unit, we conclude that the $p$-adic $L$-function is a unit times a linear factor. Hence the limit class group $X$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}_{37}$-module of rank $1$ and hence the $p$-primary part of the class group of $K_n$ is of order $p^{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 0$, i.e., $c(n)=n$ in your notations.
The fact which underlies the proof of Ribet's theorem is that the Eisenstein series
\begin{align*}
 G &= -\frac{B_{32}}{2\cdot 32} + \sum_{n\geq 1} \sum_{d\mid n} d^{31} q^n  \\
   &={\scriptstyle \frac{7709321041217}{32640} + q + 2147483649\,q^2 + 617673396283948\,q^3 + 4611686020574871553\,q^4
   %+ 4656612873077392578126\,q^5
   +\cdots}
\end{align*}
of weight $32$ is congruent modulo one of the primes above $37$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{12})$ to the cuspform
$$
 f = q + \zeta_{12} \,q^2 + \bigl(-\zeta_{12}^3 +\zeta_{12}^2 -\zeta_{12}\bigr)\,q^3 -\zeta_{12}^2\, q^4 + \bigl(2\,\zeta_{12}^3 +\zeta_{12}^2-2\,\zeta_{12}^2 -2\bigr)\, q^5 + \cdots
$$
of weight $2$ for the group $\Gamma_1(37)$ and character $\omega^{30}$.

Comment: A follow-up to this: how did you calculate the approximation for the Kubota-Leopoldt p-adic L function? Is there a reference that details how to compute these approximations?

Comment: @chaad Using Stickelberger elements, so Bernoulli numbers, as in 1.5 of https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/plp/pmzcw/download/heidelberg.pdf. Lang's book "Cyclotomic fields" is a good reference.

Comment: Only one puzzle. How do you deduce that $X$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}_{37}$-module, i.e. why $X$ can not have finite torsion part? Do you implicitly use the fact that X has no nontrivial $\Lambda$-finite submodule?